# How to submit a custom form in drupal 7

Tags: forms

I am new to drupal, but i have a requirement with form submission .For this i have created a static block . In that block some input types are there like dropdown menu, checkboxes radio button etc. When user clicks on preview button i am able to fetch the data into bootstrap modal dialogue box.So in that modal dialogue form, submit button is there.But when i try to submit the values from modal dialogue box those values are not posted. Those values sent to url.

```
For this i am using normal $_POST method.
```

I have placed this code in the block section like regualr php .

```
if(isset($_POST['sendtorfq']) 
{
  print_r($_POST);
}


<form name="rfq_form id="rfq_form method="post">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sendtorfq" value="SendData">
</form>
```

But it takes form method as GET. and when i place the mouse on the submit button it shows 
the url of that page like /process?name=somename&email=someemail.Every time when i submit the form values are posted to url . But not to post method. Please suggest me  where i was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should work with [Drupal forms api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

But here you are missing some quotes in your html so it could be the issue your form is not working

```
--<form name="rfq_form id="rfq_form method="post">
  --<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sendtorfq" value="SendData">
--</form>

TO

++<form name="rfq_form" id="rfq_form" method="post">
  ++<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sendtorfq" value="SendData">
++</form>
```

Firebug your html in browser you will see it is breaking.
Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend the [Entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) module.  Going with this module, would allow you to take advantage of the countless contributed modules that add fields via [field ui](http://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-1/issue-1/introduction-field-ui). Like the most useful for you would be the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) modules.

Rules would be used to create custom conditional actions when your form is submitted and Views would allow you to create custom displays using form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

I completely disagree with this method you did, you can achieve it by more better and clear solution,like using great `webform` module, by the way I suggest you add `action` property to your form, also register a callback menu to receive and process your data.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself familiar with [Drupal Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) if you want tight control on custom form. Or like what zhilevan has suggested, (which I totally agree—no need to reinvent the wheel) use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. 421,374 sites and over 2 million downloads! Can't go wrong with security and guaranteed peer reviewed by a lot of people for awesomeness.

**Some relevant reads:**

- [How to create custom form in Drupal](http://webemania.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-form-in-drupal),
- [Form Generation in Drupal](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7),
- [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7)